Failing to Selenium and Beautiful Soup to scrap the # of comments in a forum
For my project, I'm trying to scrap the # of the comment. There is already a num next to each comment on the website.
I've tried to find the element via class name, but my list comes out like this:
[<span class="_3SqN3KZ8m8vCsD9FNcxcki _208tAU6LsyjP5LKTdcPXD0">#1</span>, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, <span class="_3SqN3KZ8m8vCsD9FNcxcki _208tAU6LsyjP5LKTdcPXD0">#25</span>]

This is the code I'm working on:
URL="https://lihkg.com/thread/3717611/page/1"
num_list=[]
driver.get(URL)
sleep(2)

html = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
result_list = html.find_all('div', {'class': '_36ZEkSvpdj_igmog0nluzh'})
for result in result_list:
    num_list.append(result.find("span",{'class': "_3SqN3KZ8m8vCsD9FNcxcki _208tAU6LsyjP5LKTdcPXD0"}))

print(num_list)


You get it with just a little modification to your code (you save the result and getText from it). The conditional is to avoid the NoneType:
html = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
result_list = html.find_all('div', {'class': '_36ZEkSvpdj_igmog0nluzh'})
for result in result_list:
    element=result.find("span",{'class': "_3SqN3KZ8m8vCsD9FNcxcki _208tAU6LsyjP5LKTdcPXD0"})
    if element:
        num_list.append(element.getText(strip=True))

